# jQuery unchecking and reselecting checkbox programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a bootstrap modal with a form inside, This means I require to programmatically set check boxes. When I attempt to programmatically select, deselect then reselect the checkbox the reselection doesn't get made.

Whenever I call `.attr('checked', false);` the following `.attr('checked', true)` doesn't seem to make changes.

How can I check the checkbox after it been unchecked?

**HTML**

```
<input value="None" name="hazards[]" id="hazard1" type="checkbox">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#hazard1').attr('checked', true); //automated input check
$('#hazard1').attr('checked', false); //User cancels form and unchecks input
$('#hazard1').attr('checked', true); //Reopens form, but doesnt get checked
```

Comment: Is the form re-initiated (re-rendered) each time the user opens the modal window? Are you saving the checkbox's state somehow?

Comment: It looks like you're using `.attr` as if it were `.prop`

Comment: @Stryner - Thanks, havnt used `.prop` much before. This solved the problem...look like ill be replacing alot of my `.attr` with this now.

Comment: Please provide enough of your code (see the "[mcve]" guidelines) to allow us to reproduce your issue, and the context of your ur question/problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Stryner** for poinitng out this quick solution for something I have overlooked.

The solution is to simply replace the `.attr()` with `.prop()`. This is an updated syntax that replaces the `.attr`. Unlike the 'attribute' providing just a string, the 'property' provides more infomation on its property type allowing the use of bools (which are needed for checkboxes).

[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)